# How to implement duplicated inner class?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Data Hierarchy is :

1. Place

   - id
   - name
   - images

     - original_image

       - id
       - image_url
       - width
       - height
     - thumbnail_image

       - id
       - image_url
       - width
       - height

The original_image equals with thumbnail_image.

My Place class is

```
@Entity
class PlaceEntity(.....) {
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Int = id

    var name: String = name

    @Embedded
    var images: Images = images
}
```

My Images class is

```
class Images(.....) {
    @Relation(parentColumn = "origin_id", entityColumn = "id")
    var original: Image = original

    @Relation(parentColumn = "thumb_id", entityColumn = "id")
    var thumbnail: Image = thumbnail
}
```

My Image class is

```
class Image(.....) {
    var id: Int = id
    var url: String = url
    var width: Int = width
    var height: Int = height
}
```

When I compiled this project, room library returns error

> error: Cannot find the parent entity column `origin_id` in com.test.room.entity.Images. Options:
> private com.test.room.entity.Image original;

> error: Cannot find the parent entity column `thumb_id` in com.test.room.entity.Images. Options:
> private com.test.room.entity.Image thumbnail;

> error: Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
> public final class Images {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you give column name specifically, **ROOM** assigns column name same as variable name while creating tables.

In your case, you should give your parent class `@ColumnInfo(name="")` annotation to specify column name of table which should other than variable name.

So, `PlaceEntity` would be

```
@Entity
class PlaceEntity(.....) {
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name="place_id") // Add this to determine column name
    var id: Int = id

    var name: String = name

    @Embedded
    var images: Images = images
}
```

By relation **Images** class is child for `PlaceEntity`, `parentColumn` should be `place_id` in your case.

```
class Images(.....) {
    @Relation(parentColumn = "place_id", entityColumn = "id") // Parent column should be 'place_id'
    var original: Image = original

    @Relation(parentColumn = "place_id", entityColumn = "id")
    var thumbnail: Image = thumbnail
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use your 'Images' class as Entity just like 'PlaceEntity'.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all answers.

I found solutions this question.

Heres my classes.

```
@Entity
class PlaceEntity(.....) {
    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Int = id

    var name: String = name

    @Embedded(prefix = "imgs_")
    var images: Images = images
}


class Images(.....) {
    @Embedded(prefix = "origin_")
    var original: Image = original

    @Embedded(prefix = "thumbs_")
    var thumbnail: Image = thumbnail
}
```

Thanks for all answers again!